# Discord unable to share screen, and keeps asking for authentication

Tags: keyrings

I have no idea if both of these issues are related.

Everytime I open Discord I get a popup that says: Authentication required, the password you use to log in to your machine no longer matches that of your login keyring.

I have tried both my ubuntu password, and my keyring password, neither unlock this.

I am able to use Discord normally if I click 'cancel', except sharing my screen is not possible. The webapplication works just fine, except that I have to share my screen and unshare it 3 times.

I have tried disabling my keyring, but this has done nothing to change this.

Thanks in advance.